# Click event on Bar Chart in MPAndroidChart is triggered on bar column instead of bar only

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm using the MPAndroidChart library to make bar charts for some data that I have to display. In my case, when a user clicks on a bar in a bar chart, detailed info regarding that specific bar should be shown in a recyclerview as shown below:

App screenshot

[image]

Now, my click events are working perfectly fine, they display only the relevant data when triggered.

The issue is that click event gets triggered on the bar's entire column instead of the bar only. Basically, if I click an empty space above the bar, the relevant click event for that bar will still be triggered. However, I only want it to be triggered when I click on the bar.

My relevant code is given below (it's in Kotlin, but any help in Java will be appreciated too):

```
    mBarChart=findViewById(R.id.bargraph)
    mBarChart.setNoDataText("No data has been logged to the cloud yet")

    rootRef7.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener, com.github.mikephil.charting.listener.OnChartValueSelectedListener {
        override fun onNothingSelected() {
        }

        override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, dataSetIndex: Int, h: Highlight?) {
            barSelected= e!!.xIndex
            if(barSelected!=-1)
            {
                mBGListShow.clear()
                mBGListShow.add(mBGList[barSelected])
                RV2.setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext))
                RV2.setAdapter(adapter1(mBGListShow))
                //Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Data loaded, contains " + mBGList.size.toString() + " items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            var i:Int=0
            for (data: DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                var emailIDDB = data.child("emailID").getValue().toString().trim()

                if (emailIDDB.equals(currentUserEmailID)) {
                    dateDB=data.child("calendarTime").getValue().toString().trim() + " (" + data.child("beforeEvent").getValue().toString().trim() + ")"
                    BGDB=data.child("currentBGLevel").getValue().toString().trim()
                    BGDBNumber=BGDB.toFloat()

                    dateList.add(dateDB)
                    BGList.add(BarEntry(BGDBNumber,i))
                    i++

                    eventDB=data.child("beforeEvent").getValue().toString().trim()
                    currentBGDB=data.child("currentBGLevel").getValue().toString().trim()
                    targetBGDB=data.child("targetBGLevel").getValue().toString().trim()
                    amountOfCHODB=data.child("totalCHO").getValue().toString().trim()
                    disposedCHODB=data.child("amountDisposedByInsulin").getValue().toString().trim()
                    correctionFactorDB=data.child("correctionFactor").getValue().toString().trim()
                    insulinRecommendationDB=data.child("insulinRecommendation").getValue().toString().trim()
                    typeOfInsulinDB=data.child("typeOfBG").getValue().toString().trim()

                    var mBGRecyclerView: BGRecyclerView= BGRecyclerView(eventDB,currentBGDB,targetBGDB,amountOfCHODB,disposedCHODB,correctionFactorDB,insulinRecommendationDB,typeOfInsulinDB)
                    mBGList.add(mBGRecyclerView)
                }
            }

            mBarChart.xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0)
            mBarChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this)
            var mBarBGDataSet: BarDataSet= BarDataSet(BGList,"BG Level")
            var mBarData:BarData=BarData(dateList,mBarBGDataSet)
            mBarChart.setData(mBarData)
            mBarChart.setTouchEnabled(true)
            mBarChart.setDragEnabled(true)
            mBarChart.setScaleEnabled(true)
            mBarChart.setDescription("")
            mBarChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(1000)
            mBarChart.invalidate()
        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the party.
This is still a bug in `MPAndroidChart`. It does not differentiate between filled area and unfilled area of the column. If we tap on unfilled area (top, bottom, left, right), the `OnValueSelected` event is fired. I have tried everything but could not get to resolve it.

Finally, I found a workaround. I used the `OnChartSingleTap` event of `OnChartGestureListener` to capture the current y (getY) position. Then in `OnValueselected` I compare of `h.getYPx<=y`. You can do the same for x axis as well.
This solved the problem for me.

Comment: You can thank the user by upvoting his question/answer rather being thankful in post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution to problem: onValueSelected getting called even on unfilled (empty) bar area (top of filled bar area):

```
/**
 * Selected Y Index on user tap
 */
private var selectedYIndex: Float? = null

 override fun onChartSingleTapped(motionEvent: MotionEvent) {
     // Touched chart entry
    val entry: Entry? =
        chartView.getEntryByTouchPoint(motionEvent.x, motionEvent.y)
    selectedYIndex = if (entry != null) {
        //Entry is non-null which means user clicked on bar area (filled or non-filled)
        motionEvent.y
    } else {
        //Entry is null which means user clicked outside of bar area
        null
    }
}
```

And then in onValueSelected:

```
override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
    //We check for Selected Y Index is non-null (user tapped on non-filled or filled area of bar)
    //Also, we check for selected highlight is non-null and whether user tapped filled area of bar
    if (selectedYIndex != null && h != null && h.yPx <= selectedYIndex!!) {
              //TODO: User tapped on filled bar area
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just adding a bit more code to @Malwinder Singh code, if it helps any one.

your class which contains the graph should implement

- `OnChartGestureListener` which will override bunch of method.
- `OnChartValueSelectedListener`

from the override methods of `OnChartGestureListener` we will be modifying are `onChartSingleTapped`,

from the override methods of `OnChartValueSelectedListener` we will be modifying `onValueSelected` and `onNothingSelected`

set these values for your chartview

```
   chartView.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this)
    chartView.onChartGestureListener = this
```

if you have this line please `remove` it, as you need graph to be intractable

```
 chartView.setTouchEnabled(false)
```

Top of the class declare

```
 private var selectedYIndex: Float? = null
```

To remove the highlight when touched outside of the bar

```
chartView.highlightValues(null);
```

To change the colour of the selected bar

```
   barDataSet.highLightColor = getColor(R.color.colorSecondary)
```

onChartSingleTapped method

```
override fun onChartSingleTapped(motionEvent: MotionEvent) {
    val entry: Entry? =
        chartView.getEntryByTouchPoint(motionEvent.x, motionEvent.y)
    selectedYIndex = if (entry != null) {
   //Entry is non-null which means user clicked on bar area (filled or 
   non-filled)
        motionEvent.y
    } else {
        //Entry is null which means user clicked outside of bar area
        null
    }
}
```

onValueSelected method

```
override fun onValueSelected(e: Entry?, h: Highlight?) {
//We check for Selected Y Index is non-null (user tapped on non-filled or filled area of bar)
//Also, we check for selected highlight is non-null and whether user tapped filled area of bar
        if (selectedYIndex != null && h != null && h.yPx <= selectedYIndex!!) {
            val index = e?.x
            if(index != null) {
         //DO WHAT YOU NEED TO DO AS USER TOUCHED THE BAR
            }
        } else {
            chartView.highlightValues(null);
        }
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected() {
        chartView.highlightValues(null);
    }
```